# Confusing Calculus problem about limits within a "function"

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, graphing-functions

[Image of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfkcs.png)

[image]

I am confused about this problem for a couple of reasons. First of all, it claims that the graph depicts a function f(x), however, whenever we look at the graph, it is not a function. There appears to be two points at f(-1).

This leads me to my next issue: if f(-1) has two defined points does that mean it is undefined or would that mean that f(-1) would equal both of the points?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In $x=-1$ function have value only one value $f(-1)=4$.

Comment: The open circles indicate that the points the circles are centered on are not included. This is essentially the same convention that is used when graphing solutions of inequalities on the number line, and this convention should have been defined earlier in your text or lectures.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the photograph, but it looks to me like that's an open circle on the bottom and a closed one on the top, which would make $f(-1)=4$.

Comment: Oops, I missed that. It seems to be an editing oversight, because each such endpoint should be clearly marked with a filled in circle or an open circle, so there is no ambiguity (i.e. one almost never has the situation like at $(-1,3)).$

Comment: There should be an open circle at $(-1,3)$, otherwise $f$ is not a function. The notation appears to be inconsistent on the right or left of $x=-1$.

Comment: Are you being graded on this? Can you explain your reasoning in person who will grade. My interpretation is that the point $(-1,3)$ is not supposed to exist on the graph. It'd be clearer if they had drawn an open circle and it isn't clear why they didn't. Thus I believe the intended answer was $f(-1)=4$.  But you understand all the concepts correctly and can hardly be faulted for not being able to read their crappy picture. Any way, if it had two such defined points it wouldnt be a function for *exactly* the reasons you state.  (You *do* have this down.)

Comment: Oh... BTW you can draw any curve you want on paper.  But if it fails "the vertical line test" then what you have drawn is *not* the graph of a function (as depicted on a cartesian plane).  End of story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like whoever made the graph forgot to add an open circle at the coordinate (-1,3) since they have a closed/filled circle at the coordinate (-1,4). I would reach out to your instructor for clarification.

If $f(-1)$ had "two defined points", then $f$ would not be a function since by definition of a function, any input (regardless of its representation; look up what it means to be a "well-defined function" for more details if you're interested) must have exactly one output.